# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Rectangle width and height must be > 0

Tags: java, exception, illegalargumentexception, jmenu, substance

I have a peculiar situation here in an application I've programmed using a Substance LookAndFeel. In my application, as seen in the screenshot below, I have three JMenus in the MenuBar.

[image]

The one all the way on the right (Take Screenshot) is click-able and takes a screenshot of the entire application window. It has no MenuItems beneath it and works as a standalone faux "button".

Upon being clicked, it works perfectly fine. But in the console I get a HUGE block of errors related to what I'm assuming is the current L&F I'm using (seeing as this didn't happen with the System Default L&F).

Another question I would like to have answered is how to fix the opaque part of the menu's shadow, also as seen in the screenshot provided. None of this affects execution of the application in any way, I would just like them both resolved to ensure execution is optimal.

If any of my code needs to be posted to help resolve the issue, please recommend where you think thr issue is originating from (i.e. the Robot, or the L&F, or the MenuBar, or whatever). I will post whatever is needed.

edit: I have done some more exploration and it seems to occur only when any of the Menus are selected, then I hover over to the Screenshot menu. My guess is simply because it has no MenuItems to be displayed, but I could be wrong. I still haven't a clue on how to resolve the issue, though.

Here's the error log:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Recta
ngle width and height must be > 0
        at java.awt.Robot.checkValidRect(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Robot.createScreenCapture(Unknown Source)
        at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.contrib.jgoodies.looks.common.Sh
adowPopup.snapshot(ShadowPopup.java:286)
        at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.contrib.jgoodies.looks.common.Sh
adowPopup.show(ShadowPopup.java:198)
        at javax.swing.JPopupMenu.getPopup(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JPopupMenu.setVisible(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JPopupMenu.show(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JMenu.setPopupMenuVisible(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JPopupMenu.menuSelectionChanged(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.MenuSelectionManager.setSelectedPath(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuUI.appendPath(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuUI.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuUI$Handler.mousePressed(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
Source)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: No, it is just three JMenu items, the right one without any sub-items.

Comment: Three JMenus* not JMenu items

Comment: Ok, this might not be related but your stacktrace happens to mention JPopupMenu. Yesterday, I was trying to add a contextual menu to a JTable. It seems that the first parameter given to show, a reference to the clicked element, was causing the same Exception you're getting. This might have been caused by the use of a custom table model but I'm not sure. I fixed this by simply referring to the JTable. I hope this anecdote advances you towards a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Substance that is based on older code in JGoodies.  Kirill took an older snapshot of ShadowPopup that didn't have code to check for things like zero width or height.  [Current versions of ShadowPopup](http://java.net/projects/looks/sources/svn/content/trunk/src/core/com/jgoodies/looks/common/ShadowPopup.java?rev=857) look for that error and handle it properly.

Substance itself is no longer maintained by Kirill, but I do have a maintenence fork.  Could you [post](https://github.com/Insubstantial/insubstantial/issues) this as an [issue](https://github.com/Insubstantial/insubstantial/issues) there?

Comment: How do I implement this updated ShadowPopup class so it looks like it's supposed to?

Comment: Here's the GitHub commit.  https://github.com/Insubstantial/insubstantial/commit/795f74142e3343f80ff978fa52a5f45431311316.

You can also just copy and compile these three files: 
https://github.com/Insubstantial/insubstantial/blob/795f74142e3343f80ff978fa52a5f45431311316/substance/src/main/java/org/pushingpixels/substance/internal/contrib/jgoodies/looks/common/ShadowPopup.java
https://github.com/Insubstantial/insubstantial/blob/795f74142e3343f80ff978fa52a5f45431311316/substance/src/main/java/org/pushingpixels/substance/internal/contrib/jgoodies/looks/common/ShadowPopupBorder.java

Comment: https://github.com/Insubstantial/insubstantial/blob/795f74142e3343f80ff978fa52a5f45431311316/substance/src/main/java/org/pushingpixels/substance/internal/contrib/jgoodies/looks/common/ShadowPopupFactory.java

I will also be doing a 7.1 release of insubstantial sometime in January of 2012